# Space before the question mark in the title

Tags: feature-request, formatting

In [Why are there two commands doing the same: \> and \:?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643158), the title looks a bit weird:

```
Why are there two commands doing the same: \> and \:?
```

IMHO, the title would profit from adding a space to avoid misreading the question mark as a part of the control sequence:

```
Why are there two commands doing the same: \> and \: ?
```

Any idea how to do this?  When I add the space manually, the Web-page software removes it. No-break space and hair space also get removed. Perhaps, any other way to make `\>` visually separated from `?` in the title?

Answer (score 4):

A little rewording solves the problem. :)

Comment: No, rewording doesn't solve the problem (at least, not the first of my two questions in the meta-post above); rewording merely circumvents the problem.

Comment: Fair enough. It solves the problem of the question looking a bit odd though. :)

Comment: True. No objection.